# Select string from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-in

I just recently started learning SQL, and I tried to find a random string in the table - which might have accidentally put into a wrong column and I tried to find the value in the table and I used to following `SELECT` like so;

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE 'val' IN (column1, column2, column3, column4, ...)
```

My question is, can you search within a table without having to name all the column names in parentheses?

Comment: To elaborate on GMB comment, there are probably ways to dynamically / programmatically list the columns, (some kind of "reflection" if you are used to this term with programming language), but they often heavily rely on special system-tables which are very specific to the "brand" of database that you are using.

Comment: @GMB in OP's defence, it's in the question title. I've added the appropriate tag however it would be great if OP could clarify the specific SQL Server version

Comment: While there are a few cases in which doing something like this is desirable, in more cases it indicates that you haven't laid out your table(s) correctly in your database design.  You should not be storing "the same" information in different columns in the same table.

Comment: @Phil: my bad I missed the obvious information in the title.

Answer (score 3):

> `WHERE 'val' IN (column1, column2, column3, column4, ...)`
>
> can you search within a table without having to name all the column names in parentheses?

In a nutshell: no. In pure SQL, you need to enumerate the columns. The database engine needs to see all the column and table names to be able to parse the query and prepare its execution plan.

You can, however, do what you want with dynamic SQL. This means run a query that lists the columns of the table from the catalog view of the database, and use the results to build the final query, using string concatenation. Here is a small example:

```
declare @tab varchar(max), @sql varchar(max);
set @tab = 'mytable';

select @sql = string_agg(column_name, ', ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @tab and column_name <> 'id';

set @sql = N'select * from ' + @tab + ' where ''val'' in (' + @sql + ')';
select @sql;
-- exe sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not paramount, you could try something like:

```
Declare @search varchar(100) = 'smith'

Select * 
 From  YourTable A
 Where (Select A.* for XML Raw) like '%'+@search+'%'
```

Now, to be clear, if you have a column **`FNAME`** and you search **`FNAME`**, every row will be returned.

If you want an **exact match**, that would like:

```
 Where (Select A.* for XML Raw) like '%"'+@search+'"%'
```

If 2016+, there is a JSON alternative.

Comment: This would also match rows containing the value "not smith" - the `'val' IN (column1, column2, column3, column4, ...)` indicates they want an equality match not a substring match

Comment: @MartinSmith and exact match would be  '%"'+@search+'"%'

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
Id INT,
column1 VARCHAR(50), 
column2 VARCHAR(50), 
column3 VARCHAR(50), 
column4 VARCHAR(50),
);

INSERT INTO YourTable 
VALUES (1, 'Val', 'NotVal', 'NotVal', 'NotVal'),
       (2, 'Val', 'NotVal', 'NotVal', 'Val');
```

To search for the string "Val" you can then use

```
SELECT CA2.Cols,
       T.*
FROM YourTable T
    CROSS APPLY
(SELECT T.* FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) CA1(X)
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(N1.n.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname'), ',') AS Cols
    FROM CA1.X.nodes('/row/*[text() = "Val"]') N1(n)
    GROUP BY()
) CA2;
```

which returns

```
+-----------------+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      Cols       | Id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+-----------------+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1         |  1 | Val     | NotVal  | NotVal  | NotVal  |
| column1,column4 |  2 | Val     | NotVal  | NotVal  | Val     |
+-----------------+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The `Cols` column tells you the columns that matched the search string in that row.

There is a performance overhead to this approach though so shouldn't be used in most production code scenarios.